# Fix position of some circles in d3 pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I have a graph that uses d3.js' pack layout. As I add and remove some nodes from the dataset, I need the items that remain in the set to keep the same position. Is that possible?

Edit: I'm using pack layout. In the answer to the other question the solution is to use the 'fixed' attribute, which works with the force layout, but not with the pack layout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix Node Position in D3 Force-Directed Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-d3-force-directed-layout)

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-d3-force-directed-layout, which is returned as the first result of a google search for "d3 fix force layout position".

Comment: uhm no, this is about the pack layout, not the force layout