# Fix only one dimension of a node in force layout?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

This question - [Fix Node Position in D3 Force-Directed Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-d3-force-directed-layout) - covers how to fix the position of a node in a force-layout.

My question is how to fix one dimension, X or Y, of a node and let the other respond to the forces in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly supported in D3, but you can do it manually by resetting the coordinate you want to remain constant in the `tick` handler function.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
  nodes.each(function(d) {
    d.x = d.px = d.savedX; // similar for y
  });
  // do other stuff
});
```

This requires you to store the desired value with the data bound to the nodes, in the example in an attribute `savedX` (although you can obviously use any other name as long as it's not used by anything else).

Comment: Thank you!  For people who find this - there's a bit of documentation about this in the first paragraph here - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout and here - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#on