# D3 version 5 force directed layout with fixed nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

In earlier versions of d3 (such as version 3), you could add a `fixed=true` property to a node, and the force directed layout algorithm would not move that node.  Mike Bostock did [an example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558) showing this behavior.

However, in version 5, this property has been removed, and there doesn't appear to be any way to do this now.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: With fx and fy properties to position both x and y. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644069/710608

Comment: Thanks AndrewReid! If you want to make this a "real" answer, instead of just a comment, I'll mark it as the official answer to give you credit.

Comment: I shouldn't really as it's a duplicate, I'd just be copying that answer really.