# Else statement won't trigger for fixing nodes in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js visualization (v5 using promises) that I have been working on. Not the best at javascript, and maybe it's because I've been staring at the screen too long but I can't get this else statement to trigger for dblclick events.

```
 // react to double click .on() event
function doubleclicked(d) {
  if (d.fx == null & d.fy == null){
    console.log("d.fx and d.fy are null, fixing point");
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;

  d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", 22)
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
        .style("font-weight", "normal")
        .style("weight", "normal")
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
      .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 16)
        .style("stroke-width", "1.5px")
        .style("fill","light gray")
        .style("stroke","black");
  } else{ 
    console.log('whyyyy wont this work');
      // you can set null, or delete d.fx, delete d.fy keys
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
  d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", 22)
        .style("stroke", "blue")
        .style("stroke-width", ".5px")
        .style("font", "20px sans-serif");


    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 16);};

    };
```

Per the documentation and SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544007/d3-forcesimulation-and-dragging-what-is-node-fx-node-fy) I am able to successfully set the node to a fixed position (if statement executes). But I am unable to get the else statement to trigger, and I'm sure it's something stupid I am overlooking. Does anyone have any ideas?

I have added my drag funcs as I feel it has something to do with that.

```
function dragstarted(d) {
      console.log('drag start');
      if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    };
function dragged(d) {
  console.log('drag mid');
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
};

function dragended(d) {
  console.log('drag end');
  if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);
  if (d.fx == null && d.fy ==null){
     d.fx = d.x;
     d.fy = d.y;
  }
  else{
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
```

Comment: during drag you set `d.fx`. In dragend you clear `d.fx`, so for double click `d.fx==null`, you can't double click while dragging

Comment: okay I had a feeling it might have to do with that, what would be a good way to prevent drag from interrupting doubleclick?

Comment: `d.fx == null & d.fy == null` is this a typo? In JavaScript `&` is different from `&&`.

Comment: made all the appropriate changes to get the script to run. @GerardoFurtado I made the change (good catch)

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for the drag hint.