# D3 - Stop Force Graph from moving around, nodes should only stay where moved

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to create a "Flowchart/Workflow" type of chart/representation. Each node will be a "task" and then we will draw lines to connect each task to the next one so that we can layout the workflow.

This [example](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) is very close to what we want and so we've chosen it as a "jumping off point".

You can see the code for this example [here](https://gist.github.com/rkirsling/5001347).

And here's a snippet of it at work:

```js
/*
Copyright (c) 2013 Ross Kirsling

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
"Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

// set up SVG for D3
const width = 500;
const height = 250;
const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .on('contextmenu', () => { d3.event.preventDefault(); })
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

// set up initial nodes and links
//  - nodes are known by 'id', not by index in array.
//  - reflexive edges are indicated on the node (as a bold black circle).
//  - links are always source < target; edge directions are set by 'left' and 'right'.
const nodes = [
  { id: 0, reflexive: false },
  { id: 1, reflexive: true },
  { id: 2, reflexive: false }
];
let lastNodeId = 2;
const links = [
  { source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], left: false, right: true },
  { source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2], left: false, right: true }
];

// init D3 force layout
const force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id((d) => d.id).distance(150))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force('x', d3.forceX(width / 2))
  .force('y', d3.forceY(height / 2))
  .on('tick', tick);

// init D3 drag support
const drag = d3.drag()
  // Mac Firefox doesn't distinguish between left/right click when Ctrl is held... 
  .filter(() => d3.event.button === 0 || d3.event.button === 2)
  .on('start', (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();

    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  })
  .on('drag', (d) => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  })
  .on('end', (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);

    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  });

// define arrow markers for graph links
svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 6)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'start-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 4)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M10,-5L0,0L10,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

// line displayed when dragging new nodes
const dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
  .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');

// handles to link and node element groups
let path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
let circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

// mouse event vars
let selectedNode = null;
let selectedLink = null;
let mousedownLink = null;
let mousedownNode = null;
let mouseupNode = null;

function resetMouseVars() {
  mousedownNode = null;
  mouseupNode = null;
  mousedownLink = null;
}

// update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
function tick() {
  // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
  path.attr('d', (d) => {
    const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    const normX = deltaX / dist;
    const normY = deltaY / dist;
    const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
    const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
    const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
    const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
    const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
    const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

    return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
  });

  circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}

// update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {
  // path (link) group
  path = path.data(links);

  // update existing links
  path.classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '');

  // remove old links
  path.exit().remove();

  // add new links
  path = path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '')
    .on('mousedown', (d) => {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedownLink = d;
      selectedLink = (mousedownLink === selectedLink) ? null : mousedownLink;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    })
    .merge(path);

  // circle (node) group
  // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
  circle = circle.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

  // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
  circle.selectAll('circle')
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive);

  // remove old nodes
  circle.exit().remove();

  // add new nodes
  const g = circle.enter().append('svg:g');

  g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 12)
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .style('stroke', (d) => d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString())
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive)
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // enlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
    })
    .on('mousedown', (d) => {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select node
      mousedownNode = d;
      selectedNode = (mousedownNode === selectedNode) ? null : mousedownNode;
      selectedLink = null;

      // reposition drag line
      dragLine
        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
        .classed('hidden', false)
        .attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}`);

      restart();
    })
    .on('mouseup', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode) return;

      // needed by FF
      dragLine
        .classed('hidden', true)
        .style('marker-end', '');

      // check for drag-to-self
      mouseupNode = d;
      if (mouseupNode === mousedownNode) {
        resetMouseVars();
        return;
      }

      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');

      // add link to graph (update if exists)
      // NB: links are strictly source < target; arrows separately specified by booleans
      const isRight = mousedownNode.id < mouseupNode.id;
      const source = isRight ? mousedownNode : mouseupNode;
      const target = isRight ? mouseupNode : mousedownNode;

      const link = links.filter((l) => l.source === source && l.target === target)[0];
      if (link) {
        link[isRight ? 'right' : 'left'] = true;
      } else {
        links.push({ source, target, left: !isRight, right: isRight });
      }

      // select new link
      selectedLink = link;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    });

  // show node IDs
  g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id')
    .text((d) => d.id);

  circle = g.merge(circle);

  // set the graph in motion
  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .force('link').links(links);

  force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
}

function mousedown() {
  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', true);

  if (d3.event.ctrlKey || mousedownNode || mousedownLink) return;

  // insert new node at point
  const point = d3.mouse(this);
  const node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false, x: point[0], y: point[1] };
  nodes.push(node);

  restart();
}

function mousemove() {
  if (!mousedownNode) return;

  // update drag line
  dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${d3.mouse(this)[0]},${d3.mouse(this)[1]}`);
}

function mouseup() {
  if (mousedownNode) {
    // hide drag line
    dragLine
      .classed('hidden', true)
      .style('marker-end', '');
  }

  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', false);

  // clear mouse event vars
  resetMouseVars();
}

function spliceLinksForNode(node) {
  const toSplice = links.filter((l) => l.source === node || l.target === node);
  for (const l of toSplice) {
    links.splice(links.indexOf(l), 1);
  }
}

// only respond once per keydown
let lastKeyDown = -1;

function keydown() {
  d3.event.preventDefault();

  if (lastKeyDown !== -1) return;
  lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;

  // ctrl
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.call(drag);
    svg.classed('ctrl', true);
    return;
  }

  if (!selectedNode && !selectedLink) return;

  switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
    case 8: // backspace
    case 46: // delete
      if (selectedNode) {
        nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
        spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        links.splice(links.indexOf(selectedLink), 1);
      }
      selectedLink = null;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
      break;
    case 66: // B
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to both left and right
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 76: // L
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to left only
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = false;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 82: // R
      if (selectedNode) {
        // toggle node reflexivity
        selectedNode.reflexive = !selectedNode.reflexive;
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to right only
        selectedLink.left = false;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
  }
}

function keyup() {
  lastKeyDown = -1;

  // ctrl
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.on('.drag', null);
    svg.classed('ctrl', false);
  }
}

// app starts here
svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove)
  .on('mouseup', mouseup);
d3.select(window)
  .on('keydown', keydown)
  .on('keyup', keyup);
restart();
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #FFF;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

path.link.selected {
  stroke-dasharray: 10,2;
}

path.link.dragline {
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link.hidden {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

circle.node {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle.node.reflexive {
  stroke: #000 !important;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.id {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directed Graph Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

When you run the demo, each node can be dragged around (using the ctrl key), however doing so makes the entire structure move and self-align all the nodes.

What I want to have happen is that you can drag the nodes, but then that's it. They stay where you put them, and nothing goes spinning/bouncing around.

So far I'm pretty sure that the answer has something to do with the d3.forceSimulation() and/or the tick() function(s). But I'm not sure how to make it do what I want.

Thanks in advance for any info you can offer.

PS - I am working in v5.x.x of D3.js

Answer (score 7):

On the surface, the solution you are looking for is to fix the position of every node. You can fix nodes with `fx` and `fy` properties, as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10392505/7106086).

But, this isn't an ideal solution. A d3-force layout allows a visualization to self organize, if you don't want any node to float or move or otherwise self organize, then the layout isn't the right choice. But, we can easily adopt your existing example while stripping out the force but still keep the interactivity and the manual placement of nodes.

We need to modify a few things to excise the force and keep the rest of the functionality:

**The Tick Function**

The movement of nodes happens in the tick function:

```
// update force layout (called automatically each iteration)
function tick() {
  // draw directed edges with proper padding from node centers
  path.attr('d', (d) => {
    const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    const normX = deltaX / dist;
    const normY = deltaY / dist;
    const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
    const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
    const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
    const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
    const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
    const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

    return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
  });

  circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}
```

In a force simulation, the above code is simply triggered repeatedly every tick updating the positioning of all the force layout's elements: the paths and the circles.

We can lift this function directly and use it to redraw the layout whenever we change it: during a drag event and when modifying the nodes. *The drag doesn't call the tick function in the original because the simulation is constantly calling it anyways*.

Let's rename this function `draw` just for clarity.

**The Drag Functionality**

Now, let's take a look at the drag behavior:

```
const drag = d3.drag()
  // Mac Firefox doesn't distinguish between left/right click when Ctrl is held... 
  .filter(() => d3.event.button === 0 || d3.event.button === 2)
  .on('start', (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();

    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  })
  .on('drag', (d) => {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  })
  .on('end', (d) => {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0);

    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  });
```

The start event fixes the node being dragged so the force layout doesn't try to reposition it during the drag event. Since we don't need a force, we can get rid of the start and end events which just fix and unfix the nodes. Instead we can just update the x,y attributes during the drag itself, and we need to keep redrawing during the drag, so we can use something like:

```
 const drag = d3.drag()
  .filter(() => d3.event.button === 0 || d3.event.button === 2)
  .on('drag', (d) => {
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
    draw();
  })
```

**The Restart Function**

The restart function allows adding or modification of nodes and links - it does the enter/update/exit cycle for you already. In its original form it also reheats the visualization, triggering the tick function repeatedly again. Since we are doing away with the force, we can just call the draw function once at the end of this function.

**The Simulation Itself**

Now we can just remove any reference to the simulation left over, and we're good to go. Well, except for one thing:

**Starting Positions**

If we remove all of the references to the simulation now, we get a workable example. But, the original three nodes are all at [0,0] - the force simulation assigned them starting positions in the example. If we assign the starting nodes x and y properties manually, they'll be placed however we want.

Here's an updated snippet:

```js
// set up SVG for D3
const width = 600;
const height = 300;
const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .on('contextmenu', () => { d3.event.preventDefault(); })
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

// set up initial nodes and links
//  - nodes are known by 'id', not by index in array.
//  - reflexive edges are indicated on the node (as a bold black circle).
//  - links are always source < target; edge directions are set by 'left' and 'right'.
const nodes = [
  { id: 0, reflexive: false, x: 100, y: 100},
  { id: 1, reflexive: true, x: 150, y: 50},
  { id: 2, reflexive: false, x: 200, y: 100 }
];
let lastNodeId = 2;
const links = [
  { source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1], left: false, right: true },
  { source: nodes[1], target: nodes[2], left: false, right: true }
];

// init D3 drag support
const drag = d3.drag()
  // Mac Firefox doesn't distinguish between left/right click when Ctrl is held... 
  .filter(() => d3.event.button === 0 || d3.event.button === 2)
  .on('drag', (d) => {
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
 draw();
  })
  


// define arrow markers for graph links
svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 6)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'start-arrow')
    .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 4)
    .attr('markerWidth', 3)
    .attr('markerHeight', 3)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
  .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M10,-5L0,0L10,5')
    .attr('fill', '#000');

// line displayed when dragging new nodes
const dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
  .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
  .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');

// handles to link and node element groups
let path = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
let circle = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

// mouse event vars
let selectedNode = null;
let selectedLink = null;
let mousedownLink = null;
let mousedownNode = null;
let mouseupNode = null;

function resetMouseVars() {
  mousedownNode = null;
  mouseupNode = null;
  mousedownLink = null;
}

function draw() {

  path.attr('d', (d) => {
    const deltaX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    const deltaY = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    const normX = deltaX / dist;
    const normY = deltaY / dist;
    const sourcePadding = d.left ? 17 : 12;
    const targetPadding = d.right ? 17 : 12;
    const sourceX = d.source.x + (sourcePadding * normX);
    const sourceY = d.source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);
    const targetX = d.target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
    const targetY = d.target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

    return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
  });

  circle.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}

draw();

// update graph (called when needed)
function restart() {
  // path (link) group
  path = path.data(links);

  // update existing links
  path.classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '');

  // remove old links
  path.exit().remove();

  // add new links
  path = path.enter().append('svg:path')
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .classed('selected', (d) => d === selectedLink)
    .style('marker-start', (d) => d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : '')
    .style('marker-end', (d) => d.right ? 'url(#end-arrow)' : '')
    .on('mousedown', (d) => {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select link
      mousedownLink = d;
      selectedLink = (mousedownLink === selectedLink) ? null : mousedownLink;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    })
    .merge(path);

  // circle (node) group
  // NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
  circle = circle.data(nodes, (d) => d.id);

  // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
  circle.selectAll('circle')
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive);

  // remove old nodes
  circle.exit().remove();

  // add new nodes
  const g = circle.enter().append('svg:g');

  g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('r', 12)
    .style('fill', (d) => (d === selectedNode) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id))
    .style('stroke', (d) => d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString())
    .classed('reflexive', (d) => d.reflexive)
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // enlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode || d === mousedownNode) return;
      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
    })
    .on('mousedown', (d) => {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;

      // select node
      mousedownNode = d;
      selectedNode = (mousedownNode === selectedNode) ? null : mousedownNode;
      selectedLink = null;

      // reposition drag line
      dragLine
        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
        .classed('hidden', false)
        .attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}`);

      restart();
    })
    .on('mouseup', function (d) {
      if (!mousedownNode) return;

      // needed by FF
      dragLine
        .classed('hidden', true)
        .style('marker-end', '');

      // check for drag-to-self
      mouseupNode = d;
      if (mouseupNode === mousedownNode) {
        resetMouseVars();
        return;
      }

      // unenlarge target node
      d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');

      // add link to graph (update if exists)
      // NB: links are strictly source < target; arrows separately specified by booleans
      const isRight = mousedownNode.id < mouseupNode.id;
      const source = isRight ? mousedownNode : mouseupNode;
      const target = isRight ? mouseupNode : mousedownNode;

      const link = links.filter((l) => l.source === source && l.target === target)[0];
      if (link) {
        link[isRight ? 'right' : 'left'] = true;
      } else {
        links.push({ source, target, left: !isRight, right: isRight });
      }

      // select new link
      selectedLink = link;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
    });

  // show node IDs
  g.append('svg:text')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 4)
    .attr('class', 'id')
    .text((d) => d.id);

  circle = g.merge(circle);

  draw();
}

function mousedown() {
  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', true);

  if (d3.event.ctrlKey || mousedownNode || mousedownLink) return;

  // insert new node at point
  const point = d3.mouse(this);
  const node = { id: ++lastNodeId, reflexive: false, x: point[0], y: point[1] };
  nodes.push(node);

  restart();
}

function mousemove() {
  if (!mousedownNode) return;

  // update drag line
  dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.x},${mousedownNode.y}L${d3.mouse(this)[0]},${d3.mouse(this)[1]}`);
}

function mouseup() {
  if (mousedownNode) {
    // hide drag line
    dragLine
      .classed('hidden', true)
      .style('marker-end', '');
  }

  // because :active only works in WebKit?
  svg.classed('active', false);

  // clear mouse event vars
  resetMouseVars();
}

function spliceLinksForNode(node) {
  const toSplice = links.filter((l) => l.source === node || l.target === node);
  for (const l of toSplice) {
    links.splice(links.indexOf(l), 1);
  }
}

// only respond once per keydown
let lastKeyDown = -1;

function keydown() {
  d3.event.preventDefault();

  if (lastKeyDown !== -1) return;
  lastKeyDown = d3.event.keyCode;

  // ctrl
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.call(drag);
    svg.classed('ctrl', true);
    return;
  }

  if (!selectedNode && !selectedLink) return;

  switch (d3.event.keyCode) {
    case 8: // backspace
    case 46: // delete
      if (selectedNode) {
        nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selectedNode), 1);
        spliceLinksForNode(selectedNode);
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        links.splice(links.indexOf(selectedLink), 1);
      }
      selectedLink = null;
      selectedNode = null;
      restart();
      break;
    case 66: // B
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to both left and right
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 76: // L
      if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to left only
        selectedLink.left = true;
        selectedLink.right = false;
      }
      restart();
      break;
    case 82: // R
      if (selectedNode) {
        // toggle node reflexivity
        selectedNode.reflexive = !selectedNode.reflexive;
      } else if (selectedLink) {
        // set link direction to right only
        selectedLink.left = false;
        selectedLink.right = true;
      }
      restart();
      break;
  }
}

function keyup() {
  lastKeyDown = -1;

  // ctrl
  if (d3.event.keyCode === 17) {
    circle.on('.drag', null);
    svg.classed('ctrl', false);
  }
}

// app starts here
svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove)
  .on('mouseup', mouseup);
d3.select(window)
  .on('keydown', keydown)
  .on('keyup', keyup);
restart();
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: #FFF;
  cursor: default;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  cursor: default;
}

svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}

path.link.selected {
  stroke-dasharray: 10,2;
}

path.link.dragline {
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link.hidden {
  stroke-width: 0;
}

circle.node {
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

circle.node.reflexive {
  stroke: #000 !important;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

text.id {
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directed Graph Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: I just want to take a moment to thank you for such a detailed response! Wow! I haven't marked this as accepted yet as I haven't had a chance to try it out (we switched gears because coding our project in D3 was taking far too long) but I'm sure it must be correct, or at least enough information to fix the problem

Comment: Your answer just saved my day. You summed up pretty much everything about the feature I was working on. I wish I could give you more upvotes :D