# Connected text bubbles in D3.js?

Tags: d3.js

How would I create such a view in D3.js -- a central node with self-positioning outer bubbles, all containing text? I'm browsing their gallery but haven't found anything specifically like this. I understand it's good StackOverflow practice to show what one already tried, but I just don't know with which model I'm supposed to start; I played around with a Force Directed Tree with really big radii but it doesn't seem super appropriate.

[image]

PS: Icing on the cake would be to have the following connection descriptors as well, but I can also do without. Thanks! [image]

Comment: I would go for force directed graph and fix the central node eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-d3-force-directed-layout.

Comment: You need to drag and move those bubbles or just display them?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Dragging is not needed (but wouldn't hurt either, and maybe feel fun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion to extend the force-directed graph demo. Here's a quick and dirty fork of that example: https://observablehq.com/@yousefamar/connected-text-bubbles

The text in each bubble is a `foreignObject` for flexibility, since I found it easier to put a `p` in the bubbles than svg `text`. This way you can also use overflow scrolling if there's too much text. `pointer-events: none` is so that the text can't be selected, and so that you can therefore drag the bubble through the text.

There is probably a lot you can improve there too, e.g. in order to create a gap in the lines, I put a white rect behind the text, but it's an arbitrary width. I remember however that there is some `getComputedTextLength` function to get the exact width of the label text, which is probably better.