# Plotting nodes in a network graph using co-ordinate positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, positioning, d3-force-directed

```
"nodes": [
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "Rohit",
    "pos": [
      121.0284957885742,
      116.3165512084961,
      59.36788940429688
    ]
   }
  },
  {
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "desc": "Deep",
    "pos": [
      12.10284957885742,
      116.3165512084961,
      5.936788940429688
    ]
  }
 },
 "data": {
    "id": 3,
    "desc": "Deepa",
    "pos": [
      12.10284957885742,
      11.63165512084961,
      5.936788940429688
    ]
   }
  }
  ]
```

The above is the co-ordinates of nodes.

```
"edges": [
{
  "data": {
    "id": "1_2",
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2
  }
}
```

The above is a sample input for the link.
How can I create and assign the positions of nodes in d3 according to the given co-ordinates?
I've tried with co-ordinates which has pixel as unit of the co-ordinates but the above sample set does not contain any units as such.

The full code is below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 .node {
   fill: blue;
   stroke: black;
   stroke-width: 2px;
  }

 .node.visited {
   fill: red;
 }

 .link {
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
</style>

<body>
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   var width = 640,
       height = 480;

   var links = [{
       source: 'Rohit',
       target: 'Deep'
     },
     {
       source: 'Deep',
       target: 'Deepa'
     },
     {
       source: 'Deepa',
       target: 'Rohit'
     },
   ];


     var nodes = [{
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "Rohit",
    "x": 121.0284957885742,
    "y": 116.3165512084961,
    "z": 59.36788940429688
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "desc": "Deep",
    "x": 12.10284957885742,
    "y": 116.3165512084961,
    "z": 5.936788940429688
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "desc": "Deepa",
    "x": 12.10284957885742,
    "y": 11.63165512084961,
    "z": 135.936788940429688
  }
];

   

   //adding svg to body

   var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
     .attr('width', width)
     .attr('height', height);

   var defs = svg.append('defs');

   var gradient = defs
     .append('linearGradient')
     .attr('id', 'svgGradient')
     .attr('x1', '0%')
     .attr('x2', '10%')
     .attr('y1', '0%')
     .attr('y2', '10%');

   gradient
     .append('stop')
     .attr('class', 'start')
     .attr('offset', '0%')
     .attr('start-color', 'red')
     .attr('start-opacity', 1);

   gradient
     .append('stop')
     .attr('class', 'end')
     .attr('offset', '100%')
     .attr('stop-color', 'blue')
     .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

   var force = d3.layout.force()
     .size([width, height])
     .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
     .links(links)
     .on("tick", tick)
     .linkDistance(300)
     .start();

   var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
     .data(links)
     .enter().append('line')
     .attr('class', 'link')
     .attr('stroke', 'url(#svgGradient)');

   var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
     .data(force.nodes())
     .enter().append('circle')
     .attr('class', 'node')
     .on("click", clicked)
     .attr('r', width * 0.03);

   function clicked(event, d) {
     if (event.defaultPrevented) return; // dragged

     d3.select(this).transition()
       .style("fill", "black")
       .attr("r", width * 0.2)
       .transition()
       .attr("r", width * 0.03)
       .transition()
       .style("fill", "blue")
       //.attr("fill", d3.schemeCategory10[d.index % 10]);
   }


   //define the tick func.
   function tick(e) {
     node
       .attr('cx', function(d) {
         return d.x;
       })
       .attr('cy', function(d) {
         return d.y;
       })
       .call(force.drag);

     link
       .attr('x1', function(d) {
         return d.source.x;
       })
       .attr('y1', function(d) {
         return d.source.y;
       })
       .attr('x2', function(d) {
         return d.target.x;
       })
       .attr('y2', function(d) {
         return d.target.y;
       })

   }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any changes to the above code snippet is acceptable. What can I try next?

---

### Edit

I ran the code but the nodes are not accepting the positions assigned to them.

[image: Here is the image of the result that has come after running the code]

As you can see there is no defined edge in the force-directed graph and also the positions of the nodes do not change with the change in the co-ordinates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix Node Position in D3 Force Directed Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392505/fix-node-position-in-d3-force-directed-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```js
var width = 640;
var height = 480;

var links = [{
    source: 'Rohit',
    target: 'Deep'
  },
  {
    source: 'Deep',
    target: 'Deepa'
  },
  {
    source: 'Deepa',
    target: 'Rohit'
  },
];

var nodes = [{
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "Rohit",
    "x": 121.0284957885742,
    "y": 116.3165512084961,
    "z": 59.36788940429688
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "desc": "Deep",
    "x": 12.10284957885742,
    "y": 116.3165512084961,
    "z": 5.936788940429688
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "desc": "Deepa",
    "x": 12.10284957885742,
    "y": 11.63165512084961,
    "z": 5.936788940429688
  }
];

//adding to nodes
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
    (nodes[link.source] = {
      name: link.source
    });

  link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
    (nodes[link.target] = {
      name: link.target
    });
});

//adding svg to body

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var defs = svg.append('defs');

var gradient = defs
  .append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'svgGradient')
  .attr('x1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '10%')
  .attr('y1', '0%')
  .attr('y2', '10%');

gradient
  .append('stop')
  .attr('class', 'start')
  .attr('offset', '0%')
  .attr('start-color', 'red')
  .attr('start-opacity', 1);

gradient
  .append('stop')
  .attr('class', 'end')
  .attr('offset', '100%')
  .attr('stop-color', 'blue')
  .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .linkDistance(300)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
  .data(links)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('stroke', 'url(#svgGradient)');

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .on("click", clicked)
  .attr('r', width * 0.03)
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });



function clicked(event, d) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return; // dragged

  d3.select(this).transition()
    .style("fill", "black")
    .attr("r", width * 0.2)
    .transition()
    .attr("r", width * 0.03)
    .transition()
    .style("fill", "blue")
  //.attr("fill", d3.schemeCategory10[d.index % 10]);
}


//define the tick func.
function tick(e) {
  node
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  link
    .attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })

}
```

```css
.node {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.node.visited {
  fill: red;
}

.link {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I edited the question a bit because of the problem I'm facing.....please have a look at it